# Is, "He is a bit deranged," past tense or present tense?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I am writing an essay which must be in present tense. So is, "He is a bit deranged," past tense or present tense?

If it is past tense, how do I write it in present tense?

I would really appreciate if you could answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL. SE! Please note: this site works differently from discussion forums. Please only put answers in the answer box. If you have a new question, **do not** ask in the answer box. Post a question like you did here. Please **do not** leave chatty comments. If you find an answer helpful, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark. Once you have enough rep you will be able to upvote helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's present tense. "Deranged" is a past participle working as an adjective. Consider that you can change the tense like this:
He was deranged when he decided that.
He is deranged. Keep him away from the button.
He will be deranged when he hears about this!.